# Docker: get clients IP address in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-network

how can i receive the clients ip address in any docker container?

in my php application i need to check client ip addresses with $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] to control access which is at the moment not possible.

for example i am running a php-apache webserver in container on port 8080.

my ip address is :  192.168.80.177
container network: 172.21.0.0/16
container ip': 172.21.0.3

when i access localhost:8080 the ip of the docker network gateway will be logged (172.21.0.1).

is it possible to pass my client ip address to the docker container?

thank you

Comment: Just realized my answer if for the Host, but what did you mean by Client in this case? Let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. i want to run my container in production. so the client is the visitor of my web application ( running in docker poroduction ). i need his real ip address, preferred as $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the host ip as a environment variables at the docker run time, and then grab it in php with `$_ENV['your_env_name']`;

```sh
# GET & SET HOST IP
# double check this on the system you're working on.
# should work on most linux env
# Adjust NR=1 or NR=2 NR=3 depending on the ip addresses returned
export HOST_IP=$(echo "$(ifconfig)" | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | awk "NR==7{print;exit}");
```

```sh
# PASS HOST IP AS ENV
docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 -e HOST_IP=$HOST_IP --name yourname docker:image;
```

```php
// Your php script
echo $_ENV['HOST_IP'];
```

Comment: This won't handle IP changes.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert from local, that is correct you would need to redo it again.

Answer (score 0):

use `--net=host` when running your container

Comment: ...because there's a going-on-decade bug that prevents all else https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15086